# Testing RestClient::Request.execute in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rest-client

I am trying to test that 'ApiClient.do_request' is sending the correct arguments and calling 'RestClient::Request.execute.' However, my below specs aren't working as intended. RSpec is unable to properly call 'RestClient::Request.execute,' as the method's 'response' variable keeps coming back as nil, which is why I get the below TypeError when JSON.parse(response) is called. What's strange to me is that I have no issues when walking through the process in Rails console. I'm sure there's something obvious I'm missing here... Any ideas why this is happening, or perhaps suggestions on how I can test this more effectively?

Model:

```
class ApiClient < ActiveRecord::Base

  BASE_PATH = "http://api.bandsintown.com/artists/"
  APP_ID = ENV["APP_ID"]

  def do_request(method:, base_url:BASE_PATH, app_id:APP_ID, url:, format:"json", options: nil)
    response = RestClient::Request.execute(method: method.to_sym, 
                                           url: "#{base_url}#{url}.#{format}?api_version=2.0&app_id=#{app_id}#{options}", 
                                           timeout: 10)

    JSON.parse(response)
  end
```

Spec:

```
describe ApiClient do

  describe "do_request" do

    context "when all required arguments are present" do
      it "RestClient executes the request" do
        @test_client = ApiClient.new

        expect(RestClient::Request).to receive(:execute).with(:method=>:get, :url=> "http://api.bandsintown.com/artists/Damien%20Jurado/events/search.json?api_version=2.0&app_id=ShowBoatTest&location=San+Diego,CA&radius=15", :timeout=>10)

        @test_client.do_request(method:"get", app_id:"ShowBoatTest",url:"Damien%20Jurado/events/search",options:"&location=San+Diego,CA&radius=15")
      end
    end
  end
```

RSpec Error:

```
  1) ApiClient do_request when all required arguments are present RestClient executes the request
 Failure/Error: JSON.parse(response)

 TypeError:
   no implicit conversion of nil into String
 # /Users/slamflipstrom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `initialize'
 # /Users/slamflipstrom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `new'
 # /Users/slamflipstrom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
 # ./app/models/api_client.rb:12:in `do_request'
 # ./spec/models/api_client_spec.rb:13:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: RSpec error seems to be from another test. Namely "*when location 'options' are requested receives an 'options' argument*".

Comment: They are in fact the same test, but I mistakenly included the error message from an older version of it. I have updated the above RSpec error to reflect the updated test name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not considering minor syntax errors like `api_version=2.0&app_id=ShowBoat` in your `ApiClient` class, the problem seems to be caused by your `RestClient::Request.execute` request returning `nil`.

Debug or inspect the value of `response` and make sure it is not `nil`.

```
class ApiClient < ActiveRecord::Base

  BASE_PATH = "http://api.bandsintown.com/artists/"
  APP_ID = ENV["APP_ID"]

  def do_request(method:, base_url:BASE_PATH, app_id:APP_ID, url:, format:"json", options: nil)
    response = RestClient::Request.execute(method: method.to_sym, 
                                           url: "#{base_url}#{url}.#{format}?api_version=2.0&app_id=#{app_id}#{options}", 
                                           timeout: 10)
    puts response.inspect
    response ? JSON.parse(response) : []
  end
```

---

On the other hand, you are testing `ApiClient` class's implementation. In other words, you're testing that the class is internally calling some other class in specific manner. If you decide to replace the RestClient with HTTParty for example at some later time, your tests will fail (even though they shouldn't, because your class is still working correctly).

So, testing the class's implementation makes your tests "fragile". Instead, give an input and test for the expected correct output.

```
describe ApiClient do
  context "with all required arguments" do
    describe "#do_request" do
      it "returns object in correct format" do
        response = subject.do_request(method:"get", app_id:"ShowBoatTest",url:"Damien%20Jurado/events/search",options:"&location=San+Diego,CA&radius=15")
        expect(response.body).to include(title: "Damien Jurado @ The Casbah in San Diego, CA")
        # etc.
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm still perplexed as to why the 'response' variable continues to be returned as nil, but the feedback regarding test fragility is what I was suspicious of. As it stands, I feel as though I should just change the test to be more flexible. Thank you!